# Vue $watch: что изменилось в объекте

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть такой код:

```
 this.$store.watch((state) => {
    return state.objects;
  }, (val) => {
    console.log(val);
  },{deep: true});
```

Когда что-то изменяется в массиве objects, выполняется функция. Но в функцию приходит только значение всего массива, а надо получать путь до элемента, который был изменен и значение, на которое он был изменен. Как я могу это сделать?